# git status shows totally different directory than the one I'm in and the one I want it to be

Tags: windows, git

I've installed git, and I'm able to clone my github repo to my computer.

However, running `git status` vomits a list of all the files and directories in `My Documents`, even though I am cd'd into `My Documents/GitHub/hello_world`. I assume with different projects in different directories you'd want `git status` to show the status of the current working directory but no?

I've tried to search on this topic and it mostly seems to point to changing the $HOME path, which I have done to no avail of resolving this issue.

I've gone through several tutorials on setting up git but none of them mention the possibility of this issue or how to fix it.

edit: here's the output of `git status` run **from any directory**:

```
C:\Users\Takkeezi\Documents\GitHub>git status
On branch master

Initial commit

Untracked files:
(use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    ../../.DS_Store
    ../../.PyCharm2016.1/
    ../../.VirtualBox/
    ../../.android/
    ../../.atom/
    ../../.bash_history
    ../../.config/
    ../../.gimp-2.6/
    ../../.gitconfig
    ../../.gtk-bookmarks
    ../../.idlerc/
    ../../.kivy/
    ../../.matplotlib/
    ../../.node_repl_history
    ../../.octave_hist
    ../../.oracle_jre_usage/
    ../../.ssh/
    ../../.thumbnails/
    ../../.ticables/
    ../../.zenmap/
    ../../1uMNFkanFSH
    ../../AUTORUN.INF
    ../../AppData/
    ../../Contacts/
    ../../Desktop/
    ../
    ../../Downloads/
    ../../Dropbox/
    ../../FILES/
    ../../FL Studio Producer Edition 11.0.4+Plugins Bundle R2R [ChingLiu]/
    ../../Favorites/
    ../../INSTMSI.EXE
    ../../INSTMSIW.EXE
    ../../Links/
    ../../MSDE2000/
    ../../Microsoft Office XP Publisher 2003.zip
    ../../Music/
    ../../NTUSER.DAT
    ../../NTUSER.DAT{cfe0026b-8a67-11e6-bf4f-aa077fecf1e7}.TxR.0.regtrans-ms
    ../../NTUSER.DAT{cfe0026b-8a67-11e6-bf4f-aa077fecf1e7}.TxR.1.regtrans-ms
    ../../NTUSER.DAT{cfe0026b-8a67-11e6-bf4f-aa077fecf1e7}.TxR.2.regtrans-ms
    ../../NTUSER.DAT{cfe0026b-8a67-11e6-bf4f-aa077fecf1e7}.TxR.blf
    ../../NTUSER.DAT{cfe0026c-8a67-11e6-bf4f-aa077fecf1e7}.TM.blf
    ../../NTUSER.DAT{cfe0026c-8a67-11e6-bf4f-aa077fecf1e7}.TMContainer00000000000000000001.regtrans-ms
    ../../NTUSER.DAT{cfe0026c-8a67-11e6-bf4f-aa077fecf1e7}.TMContainer00000000000000000002.regtrans-ms
    ../../OFFICE1.CAB
    ../../ORK/
    ../../OWC10.MSI
    ../../OneDrive/
    ../../PROPLUS.MSI
    ../../Pictures/
    ../../PycharmProjects/
    ../../README.HTM
    ../../SETUP.EXE
    ../../SHAREPT/
    ../../Saved Games/
    ../../Searches/
    ../../Thumbs.db
    ../../Tracing/
    ../../Videos/
    ../../VirtualBox VMs/
    ../../advanced_ip_scanner_MAC.bin
    ../../cd-key.txt
    ../../hw2.c
    ../../ntuser.dat.LOG1
    ../../ntuser.dat.LOG2
    ../../ntuser.ini
    ../../pip/
    ../../qms-bmh1.bmp
    ../../qms-bmh2.bmp
    ../../qms-bmh3.bmp
    ../../quartus2.ini
    ../../quartus2.qreg
    ../../quartus_web_rules_file.txt
    ../../riotsGamesLogs/
    ../../workspace/
    ../../workspace2/
    ../../wtf.txt

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Comment: It's showing the status of the current *repository*. If the current directory contains a `.git` subdirectory, then it is your repository. Otherwise, the search goes up the directory tree. This allows you to view the status of the repository wherever you are inside it.

Answer (score 0):

So you clone you remote repository to `/My Documents` directory? And your remote repository name is `hello_world`? If yes, you should cd into the `My Documents/hello_world` directory, and then try to use `git status`.

Comment: i used the clone command from `My Documents/GitHub/`. the strange this is, no matter which directory I'm in, `git status` only seems to output from `My Documents`

Comment: if you want to work in the directory, it seems you need to add the untracked files to stage area,  you can use "git add ." to add all of them.

Answer (score 0):

You have (probably by accident) initialized a git repository in `C:\Users\Takkeezi`. Remove that with `rm -rf C:\Users\Takkeezi\.git`.